# Testing for matches within a string

Tags: php

I have a script that grabs all of the hash tags from a string and then stores them in an array, well what happens next is determined by whether or not there are any hash tags in the string. How do I create an if statement to only run the code if there are indeed hash tags in the string being tested.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<?php

$string= "Went for an awesome bike";

echo $string . "</br></br>";

preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/',$string, $matches);


if ($matches != 0) {

    foreach ($matches[1] as $tag) {

        echo $tag . "</br></br>";

    }

}
else {

    echo "There are no tags here!!";

}


?>
```

I cant get it to echo out the failure message? What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match_all()` will return how many matches were made (including 0), or boolean false on failure, so just a simple:

```
$cnt = preg_match_all(...);
if (($cnt !== FALSE) && ($cnt > 0)) {
    ... found something ...
}
```

will do. Note the `!==`. This is necessary to distinguish between a true boolean `false`, and a simple integer `0`, both of which test as equal when using the standard non-strict `==` logic.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way for checking is by changing your line

```
if ($matches != 0) {
```

into

```
if ($matches[1]) {
```

to check if there are matches on your string (since it will be false if the array is empty)

if you are validating, you can do `var_dump($matches);` to see what `preg_match_all()` returns

for a bonus, you can check your regex here on a [testing site i use](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Matches is an array.

```
if ( count( $matches[1]) != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump(array() == 0);
```

=>

> bool(false)

Check for:

```
 if (!empty($matches[0]))
```

as the array `$matches` is always filled with at least one item; but the entries of this array aren't always.